# Bootstrap 4 Column Breaks

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to replicate the following column on the right:

[image]

But keeps setting the last two boxes into another row:

[image]

Been looking at their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#column-breaks) but it does not clear to me or I might be missing something.

This is the code I have so far:

```
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                            <footer>
                                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
                            </footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                            <footer>
                                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
                            </footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                            <footer>
                                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
                            </footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                    <!-- Card -->
                    <div class="card card-body">
                        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                            <footer>
                                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
                            </footer>
                        </blockquote>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div><!-- .end Second row -->
        </div>
```

Comment: `col-xs-*` does not exist in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

> Note: instead of `col-xs-12`, you can mention `col-12`.

Check Demo [Here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/deogGz?editors=1000)

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 mb-3">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card card-body h-100">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
          <footer>
            <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
          </footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 mb-3">
      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="card card-body h-100">
        <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
          <footer>
            <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
          </footer>
        </blockquote>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card card-body">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
              <footer>
                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
              </footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card card-body">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
              <footer>
                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
              </footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card card-body">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
              <footer>
                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
              </footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="card card-body">
            <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
              <footer>
                <small class="text-muted">
                                    Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
                                </small>
              </footer>
            </blockquote>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, how can I add the text like in the first screenshot (New to Port? and Need Help?) to each section? Do I need to separate them and set up the column breaks as an offset?

Comment: @w_lpz in that case you need to use flex utilities. read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/). No need to use separate column breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the help! A lot of things has changed since bootstrap 3. Gotta bring up my game :)